# jquery posting html data to mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

im posting html to my upload.php file and im escaping is in jquery but it stores in the database as

```
%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22loungeTabsContainer%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20id%3D%22tab1%22%20class%3D%22tab_content%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cul%20class%3D%22imageLibrary%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20
```

how can i store it to the database as normal html?? code blocks are as follows:

```
var id = $('body').attr('id');
    var content = escape(NewText);

    $.post("update.php", { id: id, content: content },
    function(response) {
        $("#response").html(response);
        $("#response").slideDown('slow');
        slideout();
        $("#loading").fadeOut('slow');
    });
    location.reload();
```

upload.php

```
    $id = mysql_escape_string($_POST['id']);
$text = mysql_escape_string($_POST['content']);

// Connects to your Database 
mysql_connect("localhost", "#########", "###############") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("##########") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_query("UPDATE content SET content='".$text."' WHERE id='".$id."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the content you are sending is url encoded. You can use [urldecode](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) to decode the text back.

Answer (score 0):

```
var content = escape(NewText);
```

is not working 
try this instead of `escape`

```
var content = NewText.replace(/<\/?[^>]+>/gi, '');
```

I am assuming NewText is your actual html containing data

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to escape it in jQuery, because $.post() will do it automatically for you

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps changing the mime type to text/html - there should be a parameter available on the .post method or a jquery setting elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

First, No need to escape  in jquery, `$.post()`  doing it internally by default.

Try to check your content before sending in `jquery`. Might be encoded.